# Implementing Telerik MVC TabStrip with inner Menus

Tags: telerik-mvc

I am currently using the Telerik MVC TabStrip for navigation in my application.  However, the navigation requirements have become more involved and I now need to implement a sub-menu potentially under each tab option (by using the Telerik MVC Menu).

Does anybody have a working example of this?

Secondly, I would ideally like to bind the whole navigation setup to a sitemap file.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the menu in each partial view which is displayed by the tabstrip. Unfortunately you cannot use the same sitemap to bind both the tabstrip and the menus.